# Does Travel.SE have a shadow ban capability?

Tags: discussion, moderation, policy

Recently I have seen some questions (that I have added comments to) completely disappear from the main page.  I have previously attributed this to the question being deleted.  But I noticed today that even if the question itself is no longer on the main page (and was asked less than an hour ago, and I commented on it less than 10 minutes ago), I can still access it via "All actions" in my profile.

The only mechanism I can think of that would explain this phenomena would be if Travel.SE has a "Shadow ban" functionality that hides a question from the general public, but still allows the people that have interacted with it in the past to keep interacting with it.

Does this functionality exist, or am I just imagining it (and my browser is simply lying to me?)

---

Update: For the main question I was thinking about, one of the people who had interacted with it just posted an answer.  Yet nothing is shown on the main page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions that are downvoted so that the net score is -4 or less are not shown on the Home screen:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/

They do show up on the Questions view:  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions

(Documented in the answer on meta.SE here: [What does the Home Screen do that the Question Screen doesn't?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315952/what-does-the-home-screen-do-that-the-question-screen-doesnt))